# while converting list to string getting an extra [ in java

Tags: java, string, list, special-characters

While I am converting a list, which is having the data from hibernate query list.

```
list = query.list();
String str= list.toString();
String strArr[] = str.split("\\r?\\n");
list = Arrays.asList(strArr);
```

that list is having extra `[` at beginning and extra `]` at the end of the data. How to remove this?

Comment: Use the `substring` method.

Comment: Thought so, But why i am i getting that in the first place?

Comment: That's just due to the toString() implementation for your list.

Comment: nope, in the  beginning it's [ and at the end its ] this.

Comment: @tom All classes in Java inherit the `toString()` method from the `Object` class. The implementation for that method for a `List` just so happens to contain the brackets.

Comment: SO the only thign i can do is to subString and replace this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can we see example of input and expected result?

Comment: Str as a list of bullet points, which i am getting it from database(plain text) I am splitting the data by using next line(str.split("\\r?\\n");) and inserting in to list, and writing that list in to PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[list.toString()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) will return the objects in the List separated by commas, and included in the [] brackets.
However, `query.list()` returns a java.util.List object.

Therefore, you could use something like this:

```
List<String> list = query.list();
String str= StringUtils.join(list.toArray(), " ");
System.out.println(str);
```

will output:

> first second third

```
String strArr[] = str.split("\\r?\\n");
List<String> newList = Arrays.asList(strArr);
System.out.println(ArrayUtils.toString(newList.toArray()));
```

will output:

> {first second third}

without the [] brackets from the original list.

StringUtils and ArrayUtils are included in the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library.

Comment: Or since Java 8 `String.join(delimiter, elements)` where `elements` can be  either array or `Iterable` (like `List`) of `CharSequence` (like `String`).

Comment: For collections which are not Strings, but can be convert into one we can use stream and map values to proper Strings which then we can collect like `String result = list.stream().map(e->e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))`.